# Lookup column URL

Tags: development

I have a document library let say list a. Now i am using it's doucment as a lookup column in list b.

I am querying list b using caml query i am able to get document name but not able to get document url, any help will help.

```
        SPQuery q = new SPQuery();
        q.Query = "";
        q.IncludeMandatoryColumns = false;
        q.ViewFields = string.Concat(
                        "<FieldRef Name='Title' />",
                        "<FieldRef Name='my_x0020_Document_x0028_s_x' />"
            );

        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(q);
        foreach (SPListItem item in items)
        {
         string documentname = item["my_x0020_Document_x0028_s_x"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make 2 queries for this. The first one will get the name and then use other query to call the lookup list to get the document url.
`<FieldRef Name='Url' />` will give you the relative url of the document whereas `<FieldRef Name=\"EncodedAbsUrl\"/>` will give you full Url.

Comment: it gives me url to the list item of list a, whereas i want URL to the document in list a

Comment: I don't need link to list item but to the lookup document url

Comment: Isn't that what you want? You want the url of the document which is in the list A? Currently you are getting only the name of the document in list A. Is that URL embedded in some other field?